# Cannot Bind my Listview

Tags: asp.net

I want to bind my Listview but I can't. I dont know what I am doing wrong here. When I press ctrl+f5, the page is empty.

My Code is:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Student_ID">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table id="itemplaceholderContainer" runat="server">
                    <tr id="itemplaceholder">
                        <td>
                            Student ID :
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Registration Number :
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Student Name :
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                StudentID:
                <asp:Label ID="LabelID" runat="server" Text='<%Eval("Student_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                StudentRegistrationNumber:<asp:Label ID="LabelNumber" runat="server" Text='<%Eval("StudentRegistrationNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
                StudentName:<asp:Label ID="LabelName" runat="server" Text='<%Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:ListView>
    </asp:Content>
```

Codebehind is :

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LOCALHOST;Initial Catalog=ITCF;Integrated Security=True");
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Student", cn);
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.fill(dt);
                ListView1.DataSource = dt;
                ListView1.DataBind();
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:
first your item template is worng, and also you need to fill the data adabter form the Data Table

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="Student_ID">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table id="itemplaceholderContainer" runat="server">
                    <tr id="itemplaceholder">
                        <td>
                            Student ID :
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Registration Number :
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Student Name :
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                StudentID:
                <asp:Label ID="LabelID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Student_ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                StudentRegistrationNumber:<asp:Label ID="LabelNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("StudentRegistrationNumber") %>'></asp:Label>
                StudentName:<asp:Label ID="LabelName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:ListView>
    </asp:Content>
```

Codebehind is :

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=LOCALHOST;Initial Catalog=ITCF;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Student", cn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            da.Fill(dt);

            ListView1.DataSource = dt;
            ListView1.DataBind();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your datatable is never getting populated. Have a look at the following:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bh8kx08z.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The last 3 lines of code in your code-behind tell the whole story:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
ListView1.DataSource = dt;
ListView1.DataBind();
```

You're instantiating a new, empty `DataTable` and binding `ListView1` to it.  Thus, behaving correctly and exactly as designed, your `ListView` is displaying zero records from the empty `DataTable`.

You'll want to fetch the data from the `DataAdapter` before you bind anything to it.  Something like this:

```
var students = new DataSet();
da.Fill(students, "Student");
if (students.Tables.Count == 1)
{
  ListView1.DataSource = students.Tables[0];
  ListView1.DataBind();
}
```

Note: There may be a more direct way to fetch the `DataTable`.  I haven't worked with `DataSet`s and `DataTable`s in a long time, but `.Fill()` may be able to directly use a `DataTable` and skip my checking of a valid table in the `DataSet` above.)

Comment: yeah.. i edit my Code. i edited da.fill(dt); in my code.. but some thing appeared on the page like <%# Eval("Student_ID'%>

Comment: @Abid Ali: It looks like your page binding tags are incorrect as well.  `<%Eval("Student_ID") %>` should probably be `<%# Eval("Student_ID") %>`.  The `#` is part of the tag.